# Fourier series of derivative

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

What conditions must be satisfied for the Fourier series of $f'(x)$ to be the derivative of the Fourier series of $f(x)$?

I know that the Fourier series of $f$ will converge at all points of continuity. Therefore is it enough to require that $f$ be continuous for the above statement to hold? I feel that there must also be some conditions on $f'$.

Comment: For conditions on $f$, you're missing that one-sided derivatives exist everywhere (required for pointwise convergence proof).

Comment: When you say "the Fourier series of f'(x) to be the derivative of the Fourier series of f(x)" do you mean that the derivative of the function to which the Fourier series converges is equal to the value to which the Fourier series of $f'$ converges? Or do you mean something else? And if that is what you mean, then you want the Fourier series of $f'$ to converge. There is some ambiguity in the phrasing of your question.